# When I create any object in Parse, the createdAt attribute is not the correct time of creation.

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I just created a user in Parse.com and the createdAt attribute is actually 7 hours ahead of the actual time of creation of that object. This is happening for any object that's being created. How can I fix this issue in a Parse? The createdAt attribute is really important to the functionality of my application.

Comment: what do you mean? are you saying that there is a bug

Comment: What is your Timezone and what is the Timezone of the date stored in Parse?  Are you perhaps UTC+7 and Parse is displaying UTC?

Comment: @Paulw11 I believe this is the case

Answer (score 0):

The 'createdAt' field is supposed to contain the right value, unless they have a specific bug, in which case, it will probably be resolved shortly. The more likely scenario, is that the 'createdAt' field contains the right value, only in a different time zone than the one you expected, which gives you the impressions that it's the wrong value. Can you please try to test that? For example, create three different objects at three different times, and see if the delta between the time you created them and the 'createdAt' time match? Maybe it's always off by 2 hours, due to a different timezone than the one you expected.